# Books on real and/or complex analytic functions on Banach spaces taking values in Banach spaces

Tags: cv.complex-variables, fa.functional-analysis

I'm looking for good textbooks on the subjects.
If you know one(s), please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Chae, Soo Bong.  Holomorphy and Calculus in Normed Spaces, Marcel Dekker, 1985.

J. Mujica. Complex analysis in Banach spaces. Holomorphic functions and domains of holomorphy in finite and infinite dimensions. North-Holland, 1986.

Answer (score 1):

Also: 
Dineen, Seán
Complex analysis in locally convex spaces.
North-Holland Mathematics Studies, 57. Notas de Matemática [Mathematical Notes], 83. North-Holland Publishing Co., Amsterdam-New York, 1981. xiii+492 pp. ISBN: 0-444-86319-2

and

Nachbin, Leopoldo
Topology on spaces of holomorphic mappings.
Ergebnisse der Mathematik und ihrer Grenzgebiete, Band 47 Springer-Verlag New York Inc., New York 1969 v+66 pp.